# How to apply a character style to a run in a wordprocessing document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

When I create a paragraph style with openxml sdk 2 in c# and apply it to a paragraph every thing will be correct and it will run without any problem.

But with the codes below, when I create a character style and apply it to a run it make no change to the runs of document:

**Codes below will create and save the style to style part of document:**

```
            StyleDefinitionsPart stylePart = mainPart.AddNewPart<StyleDefinitionsPart>();
            Style style = new Style()
            {
                Type = StyleValues.Character,
                CustomStyle = true,
                StyleId = "CharacterStyle1"
            };
            LinkedStyle linkedStyle1 = new LinkedStyle() { Val = "LinkedStyle" };
            style.Append(linkedStyle1);
            style.Append(new Name() { Val = "CharacterStyle1" });
            StyleRunProperties styleRunProperties1 = new StyleRunProperties();
            Color color = new Color() { Val = "FF0000" };
            RunFonts font1 = new RunFonts() { ComplexScript = "Tahoma" };
            styleRunProperties1.Append(color);
            styleRunProperties1.Append(font1);
            styleRunProperties1.Append(new Bold());
            styleRunProperties1.Append(new FontSize() { Val = "48" });
            style.Append(styleRunProperties1);
            stylePart.Styles = new Styles();

            stylePart.Styles.Append(style);
```

**And below codes are something I wrote to apply the style to a run:**

```
            Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();
            ParagraphProperties headingPPr = new ParagraphProperties();
            heading.Append(headingPPr);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text textRun1 = new Text("THIS IS TEST RUN 1");
            run1.Append(textRun1);
            RunProperties rprRun1 = new RunProperties {RunStyle = new RunStyle() {Val = "CharacterStyle1"}};

            heading.Append(run1);
            body.Append(heading);
```

**And these are the output code of *document.xml*:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
 <w:body>
 <w:p>
  <w:pPr />
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="009531B2">
    <w:t>THIS IS TEST RUN 1</w:t>
  </w:r>
 </w:p>
 </w:body>
 </w:document>
```

*The style didn't applied to my run!*

And at the end, this is the screen-shot of the style gallery when I open the outputted document, this picture show that the style has been added successfully to the document but it didn't apply to run:

[image: picture of style in documnet]

**How can I apply a character style to a run?**

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [ECMA specification for OpenXML](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm), in order to style any runs in the paragraph you have to apply style to the paragraph mark as well :

> **17.3.1.29  rPr (Run Properties for the Paragraph Mark)**
>
> This element specifies the set of run properties applied to the glyph used to
> represent the physical location of  the paragraph mark for this
> paragraph. This paragraph mark, being a physical character in the
> document, can be  formatted, and therefore shall be capable of
> representing this formatting like any other character in the
> document.  If this element is not present, the paragraph mark is
> unformatted, as with any other run of text.

**So to fix this in your code.. try this..**

```
Paragraph heading = new Paragraph();
ParagraphProperties headingPPr = new ParagraphProperties();
heading.Append(headingPPr);
ParagraphMarkRunProperties headingParagraphMarkRunProperties = new ParagraphMarkRunProperties();
RunStyle runStyle1 = new RunStyle(){ Val = "CharacterStyle1" };

headingParagraphMarkRunProperties.Append(runStyle1);
headingPPr.Append(headingParagraphMarkRunProperties);

Run run1 = new Run();
Text textRun1 = new Text("THIS IS TEST RUN 1");
run1.Append(textRun1);
RunProperties rprRun1 = new RunProperties {RunStyle = new RunStyle() {Val = "CharacterStyle1"}};

run1.Append(rprRun1);

heading.Append(run2);
body.Append(heading);
```

**Update:**

Based on your open xml snippet in the comment, you forgot to include

```
RunProperties rprRun1 = new RunProperties {RunStyle = new RunStyle() {Val = "CharacterStyle1"}};
    
 run1.Append(rprRun1); //Adding run properties to the run
```

in your code. It is also required to apply properties to the run  seperately in order to get the formatting applied to the `run` element as `run` has its own properties section:

> Just as a paragraph can have properties, so too can a run. All of the
> elements inside an r element have their  properties controlled by a
> corresponding optional rPr run properties element (§17.7.9.1;
> §17.3.2.27), which  shall be the first child of the r element. In
> turn, the rPr element is a container for a set of property elements
> that are applied to the rest of the children of the r element. [Note:
> The elements inside the rPr container  element allow the consumer to
> control whether the content in the following run content is bold,
> underlined, or  visible, for example. end note]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Flowerking,this is output of code when I change it as you said:


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:rStyle w:val="CharacterStyle1" />
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>THIS IS TEST RUN 1</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>`

_but it didn't change the style of run1_